# How to accept an invite from a web app and login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, doorkeeper, devise-invitable

I have a `Rails` app that is using `Devise` with `Doorkeeper` to issue tokens to a web app using a password grant. My problem is how can I authenticate a user in the web app when a user accepts an invite? I'm using `devise_invitable` for managing invites right now, and the invite link in the email redirects to the `Rails` application and requires an authenticity token to set the password and then authenticates on the `Rails` side. I could change the redirect path after the password is set to redirect to the web app, but then the user would be required to login.

Comment: what gem or strategy are you using to manage `jwt` part here? once you answer that I will be able to help you

Comment: @seethrough I am not using `jwt` at all. I am assuming you are asking about the authentication portion, which is issued via OAuth's password grant using the  `doorkeeper` gem.

Comment: You are using `reactjs` on your frontend, right?

Comment: @seethrough yup, I am

Comment: How do you plan tracking logged in users on your client side? I believe you need some sort of token for that purpose. what do you think?

Comment: @seethrough OAuth's password grant gives you an access token. Here you are: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3